# Why does ProGuard break the MySQL connection, how do I fix it?

Tags: java, mysql, proguard

I am developing an application, and I don't want people decompiling it and stealing the code. Everything converts fine in ProGuard, but one problem I have is that when I try use it when it's obfuscated, the MySQL connection fails. This application relies heavily on MySQL for security reasons.

I took a little bit of time to debug, and ran it with a .bat file, and I got this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: defaultAuthenticationPlugin 'com.mysql.jdbc.authentication.MysqlNativePasswordPlugin' is not listed in "authenticationPlugins" nor it is one of the built-in plugins.
```

To make a long story short, the MySQL works when it isn't obfuscated but it doesn't work when it is. Please help!

Thanks in advance,
Luaq

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be happening because

> the classes that implement com.mysql.jdbc.AuthenticationPlugin and which will be used for authentication

are being obfuscated, and MySQL cannot find them anymore due to the name changes. Try keeping the classes that MySQL uses and only obfuscate the fields and methods that are not used directly by MySQL in them.